# Oracle database is returning string in different to MySql

Tags: java, mysql, string, oracle

I have a pattern matching code in Java, which gets the pattern from database
When I was doing JUnit with mysql database everything went pretty cool

```
Original Pattern in database 
[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{5}_[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{6}\\.csv
Mysql is retruning as expected and as it's stored.
Oracle is returning with extra backslashes 
[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{5}_[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{6}\\\\.csv
```

Why it's returning differently. Between  am using hibernate to fetch the data.

Comment: Can we see how you are inserting that pattern in the database?

Comment: That's loaded using normal INSERT queries. We don't modify/update the data. We just read the data from database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, `\` is the escape character for strings, but that's not true in Oracle. That means that this insert will work differently for each of them:

```
INSERT INTO PATTERNS (ID, VALUE) VALUES (1, '\\\\');
```

That will insert `\\` in MySQL but `\\\\` in Oracle. If you want to insert only `\\` in Oracle, you have to change the insert to this:

```
INSERT INTO PATTERNS (ID, VALUE) VALUES (1, '\\');
```

Comment: I am not looking for insertion. When Reading I want to read as it's in database without any escapes or any change to data

Comment: @NitinGurram What I'm telling you is that I think that your inserts could be wrong, and therefore the patterns saved in oracle and mysql are actually different.

Comment: but when i see the data in Toad, both are showing same data in columns :(

Comment: I executed same insertion script for both tables

Comment: @NitinGurram The same insertion script should not produce the same results in Mysql and Oracle, as explained in my answer, but if you see the same data for both in Toad (Oracle doesn't have \\\\ ), then I suppose that I'm wrong and this is not the problem.

Comment: yes. that's true. since i have the same data, i am wondering. between changing JDBC driver from 11g to 10g gave exepected result. something strange